# ashx handler DELETE request not working HTTP 405.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

I'm getting a HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed error while trying to make a DELETE request to a .ashx handler from the jquery file uploader I was trying to implement.

Referencing this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695587/enabling-put-on-iis-7-5-for-an-ashx-handler-using-windows-authentication) I've added the below section to my web.config file, but can't seem to get the error to go away. Are there any other tricks I'm not finding to get DELETE to work?

I'm using .Net 4.0 and IIS7.5 with the windows azure storage emulator running also.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Execute, Script">
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Write" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Write" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" users="*" verbs="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,DEBUG" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

And here's the front end code calling the handler:

```
<td class="delete">
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" data-url="/webservices/FileTransferHandler.ashx?f=df69bfd1-2a15-43e3-9310-3ca163e2aeb2" data-type="DELETE" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Delete">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">Delete</span>
</button>
</td>
```

I've enabled failed request tracing and it's trying to use the staticFileModule while based on the requests extension of .ashx I'd think it would try to use the SimpleHandlerFactory.

Here's the link I'm hitting: http://local.testsite.com:80/webservices/FileTransferHandler.ashx?f=df69bf1-2a15-43e3-9310-3ca163e2aeb2

Why would that link be using the staticFileModule, isn't that for images or documents like .jpg and .pdf?

Comment: I'm no expert but I'm wondering if it is significant that your handlers section doesn't mention `DELETE`...

Comment: That was a good catch, but sadly didn't fix things. I've edited the original question to reflect my web.config changes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the final web.config section. The thing I needed to add I was missing was changing the staticFileHandler from using "all verbs" to all of them spelled out.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Execute, Script">
        <remove name="StaticFile" />
        <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Write" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Write" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" users="*" verbs="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,DEBUG" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
    <tracing>
        <traceFailedRequests>
            <remove path="*" />
            <add path="*">
                <traceAreas>
                    <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI" verbosity="Verbose" />
                </traceAreas>
                <failureDefinitions statusCodes="405" />
            </add>
        </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>        
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP inside the IIS Server then follow these steps.
I have resolved the issues by adding delete verb for PHP Module.
1.Open IIS.
2.Go to configuration Editor.
3.Form Section DropDown Select  System.WebServer.
4.Select Handler,It will show you the available handler click next to
    count to  open the handlers.
5.Goto PHP_viaFastCGI and Add Delete as verb next to POST.