# ASHX file in IIS7.5 doesn't work (Doesn't open the image using ashx and shows blank)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I need some help with ashx file in IIS 7.5. This application is in VS 2005 windows server 2008.

I am trying to open images on an aspx page using ashx. When i had my website in IIS 6.0, the images were retrieved and shown fine. After i moved it to IIS 7.5, ashx file is n't working, in the sense, images are not displayed.

```
www.website.com/imageout.ashx?height=63&width=42&categoryID=15&imageID=77
```

I googled and tried to change web.config to something like this by creating a handler in IIS.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />           
    </handlers> 
</system.webServer>


<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />

    </httpHandlers>
.......
.....
 </system.web>
```

This is how my ashx file looks like

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="imageout" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class imageout : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
{
    string strMerchantID = "";
    string strImageType = "";
    string strTemp = "";
    string strlocationID = "";
    string strcouponID = string.Empty;
    int categoryID = 0;
    string PageID = "";
    string DIImageID = "";
    int imageID = 0;
    string Marquee_ImageID = "";
    bool Ismarquee = false;
    bool isCategoryImage = false;
    bool IsPageID = false;
    long? couponID = 0;
    //*
    string TownID = "";
    //*
    int ImageID = 0;

    if (ctx.Request.QueryString["MerchantID"] != null)
    {
        strMerchantID = ctx.Request.QueryString["MerchantID"].ToString();
        strImageType = ctx.Request.QueryString["ImageType"].ToString();
        if (ctx.Request.QueryString["IsTemp"] != null)
            strTemp = ctx.Request.QueryString["IsTemp"].ToString();
        if (ctx.Request.QueryString["locationid"] != null)
            strlocationID = ctx.Request.QueryString["locationid"].ToString();
    }
    //*
    else if (ctx.Request.QueryString["TownID"] != null)
    {
        TownID = ctx.Request.QueryString["TownID"].ToString();
        strTemp = ctx.Request.QueryString["IsTemp"].ToString();
    }
    else if (ctx.Request.QueryString["RegionMarqueeID"] != null)
    {
        Marquee_ImageID = ctx.Request.QueryString["RegionMarqueeID"].ToString();
        Ismarquee = true;
    }
    //*
   // TownID = "151531";
    string tempStrImageType = strImageType;
    if (strImageType == "couponlogo")
        strImageType = "merchantlogo";

    if (ctx.Request.QueryString["couponid"] != null && ctx.Request.QueryString["couponid"] != "0")
    {
        strcouponID = ctx.Request.QueryString["couponid"].ToString();
        couponID = Sabre.Common.NullHandler.ConvertToLongNullable(strcouponID);
    }
    if (ctx.Request.QueryString["categoryID"] != null
        && ctx.Request.QueryString["categoryID"] != "F" 
        && ctx.Request.QueryString["imageID"] != null
        && ctx.Request.QueryString["imageID"] != "0")
    {
        categoryID = Sabre.Common.NullHandler.ConvertToInt(ctx.Request.QueryString["categoryID"].ToString());
        imageID = Sabre.Common.NullHandler.ConvertToInt(ctx.Request.QueryString["imageID"].ToString());
        isCategoryImage = true;
    }

    if (ctx.Request.QueryString["PageID"] != null && ctx.Request.QueryString["DIImageID"] != null)
    {
        PageID = ctx.Request.QueryString["PageID"].ToString();
        DIImageID = ctx.Request.QueryString["DIImageID"].ToString();
        IsPageID = true;
    }
    int width= 0;
    int height= 0;
    if (TownID != "")
    {
        if (TownID != "0")
        {
            if (strTemp == "0")
            {
                width = 720; height = 240;
            }
            else
            {
                width = 250; height = 194;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            width = 259; height = 352;
        }
    }
    else if (PageID != "")
    {
        width = 250; height = 150;
    }
    else if (Marquee_ImageID != "")
    {
        width = 475; height = 75;
    }
    else
    {
        width = 100; height = 50;
    }

    decimal hightImageRatio;
    decimal widthImageRatio;
    int OriginalWidth;
    int OriginalHeight;
    decimal imageRatio;
    byte[] imageData;

    try
    {
        if (ctx.Request.QueryString["width"] != null)
        {
            if (BusinessLogic.BLL.Common.IsInt(ctx.Request.QueryString["width"].ToString().Trim()))
                width = int.Parse(ctx.Request.QueryString["width"].ToString().Trim());
        }

        if (ctx.Request.QueryString["height"] != null)
        {
            if (BusinessLogic.BLL.Common.IsInt(ctx.Request.QueryString["height"].ToString().Trim()))
                height = int.Parse(ctx.Request.QueryString["height"].ToString().Trim());
        }

        ASPJPEGLib.ASPJpegClass objASPJpeg = new ASPJPEGLib.ASPJpegClass();
        if (categoryID != 0 && imageID != 0)
        {
            byte[] imageDataArray = new BusinessLogic.BLL.Admin().getPrimaryCategoryImages(categoryID, imageID);
            if (imageDataArray[0] != 0)
                objASPJpeg.OpenBinary(imageDataArray);
        }
        else
        {
            if (couponID != 0)
            {
                objASPJpeg.OpenBinary(new BusinessLogic.BLL.Coupon().GetBinaryBarcodeImage(couponID));
                width = 60;
                height = 135;
                objASPJpeg.RotateL();
            }

               //For Other Images
                if ((strMerchantID != null) || (strMerchantID != ""))
                {
                    if (strTemp == "1")
                    {
                       objASPJpeg.OpenBinary((byte[])new BusinessLogic.BLL.Merchant().DownloadTempImage(Sabre.Common.NullHandler.ConvertToLongNullable(strMerchantID), strImageType));
                    }
                    else if(strTemp=="0" || strTemp=="")
                    {
                        if (ctx.Request.QueryString["height"].ToString() == "63")
                        {
                            categoryID = -99;
                            byte[] imageDataArray = new BusinessLogic.BLL.Admin().getPrimaryCategoryImages_Default(categoryID);
                            if (imageDataArray[0] != 0)
                                objASPJpeg.OpenBinary(imageDataArray);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ((strImageType != string.Empty) && (TownID == null) || (TownID == ""))
                                objASPJpeg.OpenBinary((byte[])new BusinessLogic.BLL.Merchant().DownloadImage(Sabre.Common.NullHandler.ConvertToLongNullable(strMerchantID), strImageType, Sabre.Common.NullHandler.NullHandlerForLong(strlocationID, 0)));
                            else
                                if ((TownID != null) || (TownID != ""))
                                    objASPJpeg.OpenBinary((byte[])new BusinessLogic.BLL.AdManagement().DownloadTempImageForTownPage(Sabre.Common.NullHandler.ConvertToInt(TownID)));
                        }
                    }
                    else if (strTemp == "2")
                    {
                        if ((TownID != null) || (TownID != ""))
                            objASPJpeg.OpenBinary((byte[])new BusinessLogic.BLL.AdManagement().DownloadTempImageForHomePage(Sabre.Common.NullHandler.ConvertToInt(TownID)));
                    }
                }
        }

        if (!isCategoryImage)
        {
            hightImageRatio = System.Convert.ToDecimal(height) / System.Convert.ToDecimal(objASPJpeg.OriginalHeight);
            widthImageRatio = System.Convert.ToDecimal(width) / System.Convert.ToDecimal(objASPJpeg.OriginalWidth);

            if ((widthImageRatio <= 0) || ((hightImageRatio < widthImageRatio) && (hightImageRatio > 0)))
            {
                imageRatio = hightImageRatio;
            }
            else
            {
                imageRatio = widthImageRatio;
            }
        }

        if (IsPageID)
        {
            byte[] imageDataArray = new BusinessLogic.BLL.Admin().getDIImages(Convert.ToInt32(DIImageID));
            if (imageDataArray[0] != 0)
                objASPJpeg.OpenBinary(imageDataArray);


        }
        if (Ismarquee)
        {
            byte[] imageDataArray = new BusinessLogic.BLL.Admin().getMarqueeImage(Convert.ToInt32(Marquee_ImageID));
            if (imageDataArray[0] != 0)
                objASPJpeg.OpenBinary(imageDataArray);


        }

        if (tempStrImageType == "couponlogo")
            imageRatio = 0.5M;

        OriginalWidth = objASPJpeg.OriginalWidth;
        OriginalHeight = objASPJpeg.OriginalHeight;


        objASPJpeg.Width = System.Convert.ToInt32(width);
        objASPJpeg.Height = System.Convert.ToInt32(height);
        objASPJpeg.ToRGB();
        objASPJpeg.Quality = 100;

        ctx.Response.Clear();
        ctx.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test");
        ctx.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])objASPJpeg.Binary);
        ctx.Response.End();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: "ashx file isn't working" and "images are not being displayed" - what isn't working about it? Is there an error that is displayed when you visit it? A blank page? Have you looked in the Event Viewer of the server?

Comment: The image is blank. The page opens up but all the images that i wanted to see using ashx are blank. :-( Event Viewer? I ll take a look at what it does and see if it helps.

Comment: @StevenV , I dont see any errors in the Event log. Any other ideas?!

Comment: Check the source in the browser of the ashx page.. What is being rendered there? Paste it here as part of your question.

Comment: @adaam Page source of the ashx image when opened in the browser is empty :-( There is nothing in there :-(

Comment: @Ram Please post the contents of your ashx code behind and ashx page then please

Comment: @adaam can you please check my ashx file in the question!!Thank you!

Comment: This ashx doesn't seem to contain code that would return an image file.  This was working before on IIS 6 (with no code)?

Comment: @Ram have you seen this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695587/enabling-put-on-iis-7-5-for-an-ashx-handler-using-windows-authentication) already? There are a few steps there that could be causing your problem. If these don't fix your problem then go to http://forums.iis.net/ where there are lots of IIS experts ready to diagnose your problem!

Comment: @tgolisch I tried to show that there is no codebehind for the ashx file. But let me edit my question with more information. Please give me few mins.

Comment: @tgolisch I have updated my whole page for your idea. Please dont make me wrong because its huge. I just wanted to give you as much info as i can. Thank you very much!

Comment: @adaam, I actually did. I tried to do exactly same as what it said but with no luck :-(

Comment: Ah you've posted your full code now - you are sending back a response as an attachment - have you checked Chrome dev tools (or Firebug) to see what kind of response is being sent back. There's a good chance that despite there being nothing rendered on the page itself, you are getting a (corrupted or empty) attachment sent back as the handshake isn't fully happening.

Comment: Two concerns.  Your empty catch (Exception ex) block will make it harder to tell if there was an error.  I would at least do  Response.Write("Error").  Also, you aren't sending a content-type.  What if, after ctx.Response.Clear(); you said ctx.Response.AddHeader('content-type: image/jpeg');